# Changing the song of the html5 audio player

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I want to use javascript to change the src like so:

```
<script>
function myFunctionP1() {
    mysong = "http://www.afinerweb.com/music/bensound-slowmotion.1.mp3";
}
function myFunctionP2() {
    mysong = "http://www.afinerweb.com/music/bensound-slowmotion.2.mp3";
}
</script>
```

and have some buttons to control music selection like so:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunctionP1()">set player to Song1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunctionP2()">set player to Song2</button>
```

but that does not seem to work. Can someone please point out the correct solution?

Comment: why the negative points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the src attribute of the audio, so you can assign an id to the audio element and use that to access it and set the src value in teh click handler

```js
function myFunctionP1() {
  document.getElementById('mysong').src = "http://www.afinerweb.com/music/bensound-slowmotion.1.mp3";
}

function myFunctionP2() {
  document.getElementById('mysong').src = "http://www.afinerweb.com/music/bensound-slowmotion.2.mp3";
}
```

```html
<audio id="mysong" src=mysong controls preload="metadata">
  <p>Your browser doesn't support html5 audio.</p>
</audio>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunctionP1()">set player to Song1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunctionP2()">set player to Song2</button>
```

Comment: thank you. also adding 'mysong.play();'  after each js line that sets the src allows the music to start immediately. Somewhat confusing is the fact that the id and the src are both set to 'mysong'. in fact, i set src ="" in the audio section.

Comment: now i just need to figure out how to change the music when a specific section of the webpage scrolls into the viewport. :)